# adding controls to a panel , positioning the from left to right

Tags: c#, winforms

i would like my added user-controls to be added in html-positioning way: I want them to position automatically from left to right and when there is no more room on that 'row' , to continue from the the bottom 'row' , from the left exactly like relative-position-floated-left divs are in html. Excuse my bad explanation..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use the [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9e8s203.aspx). It does exactly what you are describing (I think). The documentation says *Represents a panel that dynamically lays out its contents horizontally or vertically*.